# C implicit conversion?

Tags: c, implicit-conversion, unsigned

Can someone explain to me how

```
printf("%d", -2<2u?1:-1);
```

prints out '-1'. I assume there is some kind of implicit conversion going on but I can't seem to grasp it.

Comment: Enable all warnings: *"warning C4308: negative integral constant converted to unsigned type"* explains the issue.

Comment: Now explain why this code `if( (-2 < 2u ? 1u : -1) > 0) { printf("-1 > 0"); }` prints `-1 > 0`  :)

Comment: @Lundin You mean something like [This](http://pastebin.com/raw/Ss7pW8hb)?

Comment: @Michi Obviously you can't compile questionable code with `-Werror` set :)

Comment: @Lundin I wasn't sure, what was your Point :)

Comment: @Michi The subtle tweak I did was to take a condition operator which always evaluates the result to be the 3rd operand (-1), then make the 2nd operand unsigned (1u). Even though the 2nd operand will never be used, there is an implicit balancing between the 2nd and 3rd operand of the ?: operator, which causes an incorrect result in this case. The conclusion is that the `?:` operator should be used carefully.

Comment: @Lundin Nice one :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-2` is getting converted to `unsigned integer`. This will be equal to `UINT_MAX - 1`, which is definitely greater than `2`. Hence, the condition fails and `-1` is printed.

Comment: So that `u` there is converting both -2 and 2 to `unsigned integer`?

Comment: @Nebeski No, the conversion of -2 to `unsigned int` is an implicit conversion, as mentioned in the title. You can't compare a signed and an unsigned quantity directly, so one is converted to the other.

Comment: @Nebeski Study "the integer promotions" and "the usual arithmetic conversions".